# how to call geopy.distance to add a column to a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, distance, geopy

I have a dataframe with lat/long coordinates for the start and end of a trip. I want to add a "distance" column that records the trip length

I know I can do an assign to add a column like this:

```
test = tt.assign(distance = tt.to_lat + 
                    tt.to_long + tt.from_lat + tt.from_long)
```

this will create a new df ('test') with a 'distance' column that is the sum of the lat/long figures for the trip.

I've also tested the distance function and it works with a single row:

```
distance.distance((tt.iloc[1]['from_lat'],tt.iloc[1]['from_long']),
                  (tt.iloc[1]['to_lat'],tt.iloc[1]['to_long'])).miles
```

So, combining these two tests, what I want to do is something like this:

```
test2 = tt.assign(distance = distance.distance(
                             (tt.from_lat,tt.from_long),
                             (tt.to_lat,tt.to_long)).miles)
```

This doesn't work, generating a

**ValueError**: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My addition test suggests that the assign function will pull the four values from a single a row and add them. I don't understand why one is ambiguous and the other fine.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like the function you call is not meant to be executed with series objects. Have you already tried to use something like tt['distance']=tt.apply(lambda row: distance.distance((row.from_lat, row.from_log), (row.to_lat, row.to_long)), axis='columns')?

Comment: That works! (With an extra paren and specifying the format for the distance output as a number.) Thanks!